# Qt TableView with StyleSheet

Tags: qt, tableview, stylesheet

In my Qt project, in my dialog i've got table view and i am using proxy model and table model
to set its database from SQL. Now i want to change the color of my table view columns [ only columns[ 3, 4, 5 ].
After searching the internet, finally i've succedeed to change the color, but the color for the whole table view. I am using the following code:

```
ui->tableView->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow");
```

What should i write to make yellow, only some columns?

I think i should change "background-color" to something else, but i am not very good at CSS and i don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

You should color according to cell, not functions of `QtableWidget`or `QtableModel`:

```
void MyParentWidget::highlightCell(const QModelIndex &cellIndex)
{
 for(int i=0; i<cellIndex.model()->columnCount(); i++)
 {
  for(int j=0; j<cellIndex.model()->rowCount(); j++)
  {
   if(i == cellIndex.column() && j == cellIndex.row())
   {
    ((QStandardItemModel*)cellIndex.model())->item(cellIndex.row(),     i)->setData(QBrush(Qt::yellow),
Qt::BackgroundRole);
   }
   else
   {
    ((QStandardItemModel*)cellIndex.model())->item(cellIndex.row(),  i)->setData(QBrush(Qt::white),
Qt::BackgroundRole);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the help, but nothing works, i've tried your advices. I don't even get the ->item() function in my intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

No way over style sheets, you need to do it programmatically!
Take a look at this example for the background color of the rows:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10832